# Python - update records with for loop

Tags: python, sqlite

firstly apologies for the basic question, just starting off with Python.

I have the following code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sqb")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE type LIKE 'C%'"

cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()
    
for row in data:
    print (row[0])
    cursor.execute("UPDATE report SET route='ABCDE'")
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Why is it updating all records and not just the filtered records from sql query, even though the print (row[0]) just shows the filtered records.

Many thanks.

Comment: You have no `WHERE` condition in the `UPDATE` query, so how should it know that you only want to update a specific row?

Comment: Why do you need a loop? `UPDATE report SET route = 'ABCDE' WHERE type LIKE 'C%'`

Answer (score 0):

What's actually happening is you are running this query for each record returned from the `SELECT` query.

```
UPDATE report SET route='ABCDE'
```

If you only want to update `route` where `type` starts with C add the criteria to the `UPDATE` query and execute it once.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sqb")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE type LIKE 'C%'"

cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("UPDATE report SET route='ABCDE' WHERE type LIKE 'C%'")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: There's no need for the `SELECT` query now, since it doesn't use `data`.